# Combine Observables A and B: Should only trigger if A has data; take from B if data or default

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an application communicating with a device via serial port. Every sent command is answered by a data event containing the status/answer. Basically there are commands changing the device and a command which just returns the status. Every time the last command has been answered (so upon receiving data) the app should send the next command or as a default query the status. I'm trying to model this with rxjs.
My idea here is that there is a command observable and a data observable derived from the data event. These two should be combined in such a way, that the resulting observable only emits values, when there is data and combine it with a command or the default command (request status), if no command came down the command stream.

```
data:     ---------d---d-----d---------d------d-------
command:  --c1---c2----------------------c3-----------
______________________________________________________
combined  ---------c1--c2----dc--------dc-----c3
```

dc is the default command. Also no commands should be lost.

Currently I have an implementation with a anonymous subject, implementing the observable and observer myself. Collecting commands from the command stream in an array, subscribing to the data event, publish the data by hand with onNext and sending the next command from the array or the default. This works, but I have the feeling this could be expressed more elegantly with rxjs.

One approach was to have a separate default_command stream, repeating the default command every 100ms. This was merged with the command stream and then zipped with the data stream. The problem here was the merged command stream, because it piled up default commands, but the default command should only apply, if there is no other command.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to:

- subscribe to the command stream and queue the results (in an array)
- Apply a mapping operation to the data stream which will pull from the queue (or use default if the queue is empty).

We can wrap this up into a generic observable operator.  I'm bad with names, so I'll call it `zipWithDefault`:

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.zipWithDefault = function(bs, defaultB, selector) {
  var source = this;
  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var sourceSubscription = new Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable(),
      bSubscription = new Rx.SingleAssignmentDisposable(),
      subscriptions = new Rx.CompositeDisposable(sourceSubscription, bSubscription),
      bQueue = [],
      mappedSource = source.map(function(value) {
        return selector(value, bQueue.length ? bQueue.shift() : defaultB);
      });

    bSubscription.setDisposable(bs.subscribe(
      function(b) {
        bQueue.push(b);
      },
      observer.onError.bind(observer)));

    sourceSubscription.setDisposable(mappedSource.subscribe(observer));

    return subscriptions;
  });
};
```

And use it like so:

```
combined = dataStream
  .zipWithDefault(commandStream, defaultCommand, function (data, command) {
    return command;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `sample` operator would be your best bet.  Unfortunately, it does not come with a built in default value, so you would have to roll your own from the existing operator:

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.sampleWithDefault = function(sampler, defaultValue){
var source = this;

return new Rx.AnonymousObservable(function (observer) {
      var atEnd, value, hasValue;

      function sampleSubscribe() {
          observer.onNext(hasValue ? value : defaultValue);
          hasValue = false;
      }

      function sampleComplete() {
          atEnd && observer.onCompleted();
      }

      return new Rx.CompositeDisposable(
        source.subscribe(function (newValue) {
          hasValue = true;
          value = newValue;
        }, observer.onError.bind(observer), function () {
          atEnd = true;
        }),
        sampler.subscribe(sampleSubscribe, observer.onError.bind(observer), sampleComplete)
      );
    }, source);
}
```

You can achieve the queuing behavior using the `controlled` operator.  Thus your final data chain would look like so:

```
var commands = getCommandSource().controlled();
var pipeline = commands
  .sampleWithDefault(data, defaultCommand)
  .tap(function() { commands.request(1); });
```

Here is a full example:

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.sampleWithDefault = function(sampler, defaultValue) {
  var source = this;

  return new Rx.AnonymousObservable(function(observer) {
    var atEnd, value, hasValue;

    function sampleSubscribe() {
      observer.onNext(hasValue ? value : defaultValue);
      hasValue = false;
    }

    function sampleComplete() {
      atEnd && observer.onCompleted();
    }

    return new Rx.CompositeDisposable(
      source.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        hasValue = true;
        value = newValue;
      }, observer.onError.bind(observer), function() {
        atEnd = true;
      }),
      sampler.subscribe(sampleSubscribe, observer.onError.bind(observer), sampleComplete)
    );
  }, source);
}

var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();

var onNext = Rx.ReactiveTest.onNext;
var onCompleted = Rx.ReactiveTest.onCompleted;

var data = scheduler.createHotObservable(onNext(210, 18), 
                                         onNext(220, 17),
                                         onNext(230, 16),
                                         onNext(250, 15),
                                         onCompleted(1000));

var commands = scheduler.createHotObservable(onNext(205, 'a'), 
                                             onNext(210, 'b'), 
                                             onNext(240, 'c'), 
                                             onNext(400, 'd'), 
                                             onCompleted(800))
  .controlled(true, scheduler);


var pipeline = commands
  .sampleWithDefault(data, 'default')
  .tap(function() {
    commands.request(1);
  });

var output = document.getElementById("output");

pipeline.subscribe(function(x) {
  
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var text = document.createTextNode(x);
  
  li.appendChild(text);
  output.appendChild(li);
    
  
});

commands.request(1);

scheduler.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.2/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.2/rx.testing.js"></script>
<div>
  
  <ul id="output" />
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using the [scan](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md) function. In the accumulated value the commands are stored for which no data response has been received yet.

```
var result = Rx.Observable
   .merge(data, command)
   .scan(function (acc, x) {
        if (x === 'd') {
            acc.result = acc.commands.length > 0 ? acc.commands.shift() : 'dc';
        } else {
            acc.result = '';
            acc.commands.push(x);
        }
        return acc;
   }, {result: '', commands: []})
   .map(function (x) {
      return x.result;
   })
   .filter(function (x) {
       return x !== '';
   });
```

Please find a complete more detail here: http://jsbin.com/tubade/edit?html,js,console